# Set The Alarm Based On JSonArray

Tags: android, json, android-alarms

I want to build some application that run in background after i have submit it.

So for the first i will input some id.

Next when i press submit button, it will give passing the value into web service and the web service give response in json_encode format.

And which content in that json array, i want to setup alarm based on everyday , every hour from json array.

This is my json result from web service :

```
{
"length":
[
  {
      "kode_schedule":"sch0001",
      "kode_matkul":"TIB01",
      "title":"Basis Data",
      "ruang":"501",
      "latitude":"-6.18861653446272",
      "longitude":"106.801122526546",
      "lantai":"5",
      "day":"Tuesday",
      "hour":"17:45:00"
  },          
  {
      "kode_schedule":"sch0001",
      "kode_matkul":"TIB02",
      "title":"Pemrograman Berorientasi Objek",
      "ruang":"LABB",
      "latitude":"-6.18864706134991",
      "longitude":"106.801161122636",
      "lantai":"5",
      "day":"Tuesday",
      "hour":"19:30:00"
   }
]
}
```

So from that result, it shows "hour", and "day". From that, i want to setup alarm based on hour and day.

Can u help me with the logical/code/anything posibility ?

This is my alarm code :

```
public void startAt10() {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 1000 * 60 * 20;

        /* Set the alarm to start at 10:30 AM */
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

        /* Repeating on every 20 minutes interval */
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000 * 60 * 20, pendingIntent);
    }
```

And this is my jsonparsing :

```
try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", txtNim.getText().toString()));
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://studentstracking.hol.es/installation.php", "POST", param);
                JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("length");
```

Thank you before

Comment: So you don't know how to parse the JSON or what?

Comment: I would like to ask about any logical possibility. Like what should i do, or what should i use to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, just like this (i parse json from [themoviedb](https://api.themoviedb.org)).
and will notify me on 08:00 am, full source, here : https://gist.github.com/im-o/fad883b73c7a56c3ce0150800e6acf3b

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    String currentDate = AllOtherMethod.getCurrentDates();
    Log.d(TAG, "Running date : " + currentDate);
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=" + API_KEY + "&primary_release_date.gte=" + currentDate + "&primary_release_date.lte=" + currentDate;
    Log.e(TAG, "getCurrentthemoviedb: " + url);
    client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            String result = new String(responseBody);
            Log.d(TAG, result);
            try {
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(result);
                int totalResult = responseObject.getInt("total_results");
                for (int i = 0; i < totalResult; i++) {
                    String titleMovie = responseObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
                    String strRelease = context.getResources().getString(R.string.str_release);
                    String message = titleMovie + ", " + strRelease;
                    showAlarmNotification(context, titleMovie, message, notifId+i);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });

}
```

this is my alarmManager

```
public void setReleaseAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverRelease.class);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notifId, intent, 0);
    if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

and this is my notification

```
private void showAlarmNotification(Context context, String title, String message, int notifyId) {
    String CHANNEL_ID = "Channel_2";
    String CHANNEL_NAME = "AlarmManagerRelease channel";
    NotificationManager notificationManagerCompat = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_date_range_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent))
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setSound(alarmSound);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                CHANNEL_NAME,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        if (notificationManagerCompat != null) {
            notificationManagerCompat.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    if (notificationManagerCompat != null) {
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(notifyId, notification);
    }
}
```

**And call method on your ACTIVITY click eventListener or other**

```
private AlarmReceiverRelease alarmReceiverRelease;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder);
    alarmReceiverRelease = new AlarmReceiverRelease();
}
...
private void setAlarmDaily(){
        alarmReceiverDaily.setOneTimeAlarm(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must figure out how to convert the day and hour to int so you can pass it to calendar. First one is the day which is Day of Week so you can use this function

```
private int parseDayOfWeek(String day, Locale locale)
            throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E", locale);
        Date date = dayFormat.parse(day);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        return dayOfWeek;
    }
```

and then to parse your hour you can use [String.split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) which will split your hour string to three parts (hour, minute and second).

This is an overview of what your code will look like

```
int size = array.length();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    JSONObject data = array.getJSONObject(i);
    int dayOfWeek = parseDayOfWeek(data.getString("day"), Locale.US);
    String[] time = data.getString("hour").split(":");
    startAlarm(dayOfWeek, time[0], time[1]):
}
```

where startAlarm is your startAt10() function but with 3 parameter (Day of week, hour and minute) so you can pass it to your Calendar object.

Comment: But my startAlarm is in different activity. So what it should be to be written ?

Comment: Create a new function if the purpose of the function startAt10() and startAlarm is different.